# How were the frequencies of the Zeeman effect derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, schroedinger-equation

The Zeeman effect in quantum physics is basically when electrons feel different effects of an external magnetic field (due to their different orientations of angular momentum), thus electrons making a transition between the formerly degenerate orbits will produce spectral lines with slightly different energies, this is the Zeeman effect. The 3 frequencies of these split lines are given as:

$v=v_0$, $v=v_0-\frac{eB}{4}\pi \mu$ and $v=v_0+\frac{eB}{4}\pi \mu$ where $v_0$ is the frequency of the spectral line in the absence of a magnetic field and $\mu$ is the reduced mass

However my textbook (An Introduction to Modern Astrophysics by Carroll Ostlie) merely gives us these 3 values but does not give the derivation and I am curious as to how these are derived. Thank you!

Comment: You can find this in a good introductory QM textbook, e.g. I imagine it is in Griffiths (though I don't have a copy to confirm). Briefly, this is place where the perturbation theory of quantum mechanics is applied to the hydrogen system with a weak external magnetic field.

Comment: $\mu$ is the Bohr magneton, a unit of magnetic moment, not reduced mass.